# RESTFul API POST request

Tags: php, api, rest, request

I want to send sms with the Restful API of bulksmsonline.com, but I don't what is wrong with my code.
The credentials are real il you want to make a test.

https://bulksmsonline.com/developers/

Restful API section

Here is my code:

```
    $tok=file_get_contents('https://restapi.bulksmsonline.com/rest/api/v1/sms/gettoken/username/ngosda367/password/Tempcred01');
    $toke =json_decode($tok, true);
    $token=$toke['token'];

    $data = json_encode(
        array(
            'from' => 'TEST',
            'to' => '332698741113',
            'type'=> 'Text',
            'content'=> 'Test',
            'sendDateTime'=> '2020/07/07'
            ))
    ;

    $options = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header' => "Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n" .
                        "Content-length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n" .
                        "Authorization Token: " . base64_encode("$token") . "\r\n",
            'content' => $data
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($options);

    $url = 'https://restapi.bulksmsonline.com/rest/api/v1/sms/send';

    $result = file_get_contents($url,false,$context);
    var_dump($result);
```

Here is the response I get:

```
 failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Reques. bool(false)
```

THKS for your help

Comment: You're POSTing data, revise your Content-Type ...

Comment: @LarsStegelitz I tried with  "Content-type: application/json\r\n" but I get the same error

Comment: try "Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencode" or "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" or "Content-Type: text/plain"

Comment: Hi @LarsStegelitz thks, for all these propositions, I get the same result : Warning: file_get_contents(https://restapi.bulksmsonline.com/rest/api/v1/sms/send): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in /htdocs/vishal.php on line 30
bool(false)

Comment: I toyed with the code.. still some issues, f.e. "Authorization Token" header must be named "token" and the value must not be base64_encoded again. Nevertheless, I either got "bad request", "unsupported media type", "unauthorized" or a 500 Server error... No combination seems working.. I would suggest you ask the vendor of that service for support.

Comment: thanks  big @LarsStegelitz

Answer (score 0):

Try using get_last_error() (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php) and see what is up. Or do a curl request and see what error it returns with curl_error() (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php).